# How to initialize a variable twice?

Tags: variables, initialization, processing

I'm trying to initialize a variable twice in 2 different functions without the second initialization having effect on the first.

```
float X;

void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
  background(255);
}
void draw() 
{
  Rect1();
  Rect2();
}

void Rect1()
{
  fill(255,0, 0);
  rect(X, 20, 40, 40);
  X=20;
}

void Rect2()
{ 
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(X, 200, 40, 40);
  X=50;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve, because as it stands now the simplest answer would be "use 2 variables" or "declare them inside the function" but that would respectively make interaction impossible and make them invisible outside their function.

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to achieve here. You've declared "X" as a global variable. But you probably either want to make it a local variable declared at the top of both Rect1() and Rect2(), or you may want to pass a reference or pointer to the variable into each function and then the caller (draw()) can use different variables for the calls to Rect1() and Rect2().

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please tell what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems to be "demonstration" code, but it doesn't really do anything significant other than show that you probably need to first sit down and learn a bit about Processing before you continue - hit up processing.org and run through some of the tutorials. It's worth it.

The code you gave can be written much more sensibly, but instead I'll answer the question; Processing uses a variation on Java's scoping rules: a local variable trumps an object instance variable, which trumps a global variable:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 50;

class Thing {
  int y = 10;    
  Thing() {
    // x is global, y is global and object instance
    println("x (in Thing): "+x);
    println("y (in Thing): "+y);
    declareAndCheck();
  }
  void declareAndCheck() {
    // now we make some local variables: they win.
    int x = 40;
    int y = 100;
    println("x (local declared): "+x);
    println("y (local declared): "+y);
  }
}

void setup() {
  println("x (global): "+x);
  println("y (global): "+y);
  Thing t = new Thing();
  // and global is still global
  println("x (global, again): "+x);
  println("y (global, again): "+y);
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
x (global): 0
y (global): 50
x (in Thing): 0
y (in Thing): 10
x (local declared): 40
y (local declared): 100
x (global, again): 0
y (global, again): 50
```

Why? First we see this:

```
x (global): 0
y (global): 50
```

because x and y are global variables with values 0 and 50. Simple enough. then we see:

```
x (in Thing): 0
y (in Thing): 10
```

because in the "Thing" object, we have an object instance variable 'y', which wins the naming conflict between it, and the global variable.

Then we enter declareAndCheck, where we see:

```
x (local declared): 40
y (local declared): 100
```

because we now have a global x, and a local x, and local always wins, and we have an instance y, and a local y, and again local always wins.

Finally we print x and y in global context again, and because there is no conflict, we see:

```
x (global, again): 0
y (global, again): 50
```

And if that did not make sense to you, run through those tutorials, they teach you programming in Processing =)